# Marklogic:How to Search documents with regex?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have recently started working on MarkLogic 10 Database

What I need to do is find the documents who have id like

> wew35r-ui856-iiu

When I query like this

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:Qname("id"),".*\-.*")
```

I get 0 results

but
when I do

```
fn:matches("wew35r-ui856-iiu",".*\-.*")
It return true
```

And surprisingly when I do

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:Qname("id"),"*")
```

I get whole list which includes **wew35r-ui856-iiu** as well.

I had looked into the documentation and all but was not able to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Full regex patterns are not supported for [`cts:element-value-match`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-match), only wildcard patterns.

To use a wildcard pattern to look for values that contain a dash `-`:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("id"),"*-*")
```

And then if you needed, you could filter those results with a more specific regex in a predicate filter:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("id"),"*-*")[matches(., "(\w+-\w+){2}")]
```

Comment: A footnote on this useful explanation:  `cts:element-value-match()` matches documents based on a query over indexes where `fn:matches()` filters by inspecting documents in memory. For good performance at scale, it's best to do as much querying on indexes and as little filtering in memory as possible.